# macro collisions in third party libraries

Tags: c++, macros

I'm using **[yojimbo](https://github.com/networkprotocol/yojimbo)** - a networking library and **[spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog)** - a logging library for a game that I'm working on. When I try to compile a source file with headers of both yojimbo and spdlog, I get macro collisions resulting in lots of errors given by g++.

Source files with either of the headers but not both compile ok.

Is there a way to avoid macro collision in these third party libraries?

Comment: Unless the libraries have workarounds for this issue (a configuration flag to define all macros with a library prefix, or something along those lines), you should complain on bug trackers of both libraries.

Comment: Please share the compiler errors - which macros etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid macro collision in these third party libraries?

Yes. Simplest solution is to not include both headers that define the conflicting macros into same translation unit. If that is not sufficient, then one potential solution is to undefine the conflicting macro after including first one. If you need both macros, then you can rewrite it with another name after the undefinition.